# Get topmost aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I am trying to find the count of different path parameters using elasticsearch query

```
{
    "size":0,
    "aggs" : {
        "genres" : {
            "terms" : {
              "field" : "path.keyword"
            }
        }
}
```

However it is not returning the path with highest counts. Its returning some random 10 paths with counts. To get paths with topmost frequencies, I modified it to

```
{
    "size":0,
    "aggs" : {
        "genres" : {
            "terms" : {
              "field" : "path.keyword"
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "top_hits" : {
              "size":11
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't change previous response instead adds some new documents in response. I can't find a way to get topmost frequencies. Please suggest some way.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the buckets can be customized by setting the `order` parameter. By default, the buckets are ordered by their **doc_count** descending. It is possible to change this behaviour as documented as below:. [see](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order)

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "path.keyword",
        "size": 100,
        "order" : { "_count" : "asc" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not giving global maximum values. What this is doing is that whatever results were being returned earlier, its sorting them.